# Wordpress ACF plugin how to change validation rules for a specific field belonging to a cloned group field?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

My clone field "Services" has "Fields" set as "All fields from Section:services field group". My field group "Section: services" contains several fields including one called "Title" which I've set as required.

Now in my clone field "Services" I want "Title" to NOT be required. Problem is, if I try to make it not required in "Section:services", this update doesn't extend to the "Services" clone field, where "Title" is still required.

Once a field group is cloned, is there not any way to changes those fields inside the cloned field?

EDIT:

My "Section: Services" field group containing the "Title" field whose required status I wanna change in the clone field:

[image]

My "Services" clone field containing "All fields from Section: Services field group" (it is within this clone field that I want my "Title" field to NOT be required any more):

[image]

Comment: I'd like to help you, but your question is not clear enough! Please explain exactly what you have and what you're trying to do by providing some screenshots and/or a sample code of what you've tried so far. Please also use the same terminologies used by "ACF" itself. For example, you're saying `group field` but "ACF" says `field group`. It's confusing when you use the incorrect terminologies. Also please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which would help people who are trying to help you solve your problem. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Ruvee, I edited my question with screenshots and I also corrected the ambiguity about "group field <> field group": I did mean "group field". Sorry for that!

Comment: No worries! Thanks for clearing things  up! I just posted an answer to your question. Let me know if you could get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: you want `"Title" required in "Section: Services"`  & `"Title" NOT required in "Sections" (this group has clone of 'Section: Services')` , right ?

Answer (score 2):

> *"I want to do that only for one particular field"*

Since you want to apply that modification only for a specific field, then you would need a `unique` value by which you would be able to target that specific field.

"ACF" assigns a `unique key`, for each field, called `"Field Key"`. We could use this value to target any specific field that we would like to! All we need to find out this value, for any field, is to use `Screen Options` and check the `Field Keys` checkbox, like the following screenshot:

[image]

Now we can target that specific field like this:

```php
add_filter("acf/pre_render_field", "ruvee_changing_required_field", 10, 2);

function ruvee_changing_required_field($fields, $post_id)
{
    // DO NOT forget to change this value to the unique value for your field  
    if ("field_64c2e81235358" == $fields["key"]) {
        $fields["required"] = 0;
    }
    return $fields;
}  

// DO NOT forget to change this value to the unique value for your field
add_filter("acf/validate_value/key=field_64c2e81235358", "ruvee_changing_validation_rules", 10, 4);

function ruvee_changing_validation_rules($valid, $value, $field, $input)
{
    return true;
}
```

Tested and works seamlessly on wordpress `Version 6.2` and ACF `Version 6.1.7`!

---

#### Answering the follow-up question about development versus production environments

There are multiple ways to deal with this issue. The two most obvious ones, that I can think of at this moment, are as follows:

1- Creating a `"menu section/setting page"`, then writing and reading the key to and from the `options table` using [`update_option`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/) and [`get_option`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) functions.

**This is the easiest, fastest and less confusing way of dealing with this problem. I would recommend this solution over the next one!**

2- Getting the key from database using a custom query. A query like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `wp_postmeta` 
WHERE (CONVERT(`meta_key` USING utf8) LIKE '%title%'
AND CONVERT(`meta_value` USING utf8) LIKE '%field_%')
```

and the results of this query would be like this:

[image]

Since your field names are the same (i.e `"Title"`), this query could get pretty tricky pretty quick!

This is a more advanced way of dealing with this problem and requires me or anybody to know your wordpress setup, post types, all of the acf fields etc.

So my answer for your follow-up question would be to use the first solution.

Comment: Thank you @Ruvee, one issue though is that the ID of that field won't be the same on my local setup, on staging environment and on production environment. Is there a way to make it work on any environment? If not, what would you suggest?

Comment: You're welcome! Yes there are multiple ways to solve the problem about development vs. production environments. I just updated my answer and talked about these ways!

Comment: Thanks @Ruvee! My issue with solution #1 is that adding a brand new option item in the dashboard sidebar menu sounds quite obstrusive for some tiny thing (making some sub field optional). Unless there's a way to hide it without losing access to it from the code but I assume that's not possible. And solution #2 sounds problematic as I have many different fields named "title" on this project. Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: There are always trade-offs! If you have many fields named "title", then it's not a "tiny thing". It'll make your life easier and it does not have to be on the main dashboard, you could create a "sub-menu" under the "settings page" and you would barely notice it on a daily basis. It's like, `"set it once, and forget all about it"` kind of thing! Plus, you have one single source of truth. In the wordpress universe, that's what most plugin/theme developers do for their `"API keys", "tiny/huge configs"` etc.

Comment: Here's a `quote` from `ACF support team`: ["There really isn’t a reliable way to get the field key using PHP. "](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/how-to-get-field-reference/?#post-148324)

Comment: Thanks @Ruvee. I was indeed able to nest my new option page under Settings. But now I'm confused about #1 ("Creating a 'menu section/setting page' then writing and reading the key to and from the options table using update_option and get_option functions"). What do you mean by "the key"? Do you mean the id of the "Title" field? If we can programmatically get that id, why using an option page in the first place? I assume I completely misunderstood your idea here. It'd be great if you could clarify :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this programmatically.

In the example i am going to provide you with i have created two Field groups.

One called `Services` containing the field Title named `title` and the other called `Clone Services` where on the `Fields` i have selected `All fields from Services field group`, Display: `Seamless (replace this field with selected fields)` and enabled the option `Prefix Field Names`. As a result the Title field in the Cloned group is named `clone_title`. You can replace the `clone` and `title` parts with the actual names of your fields.

Now on its simple form you would need two hooks which can be placed in a custom plugin or in your functions.php file of your active theme. Please note that if you are not using a child theme, when you update your theme these would be overwritten and you would need to re-apply them.

```
// Removes the required indication when the field is rendered in the backend.
add_filter( 'acf/pre_render_field', function ( $field, $pid ) {
    if ( 'clone_title' === $field['name'] ) {
        $field['required'] = 0;
    }
    return $field;
}, 10, 2 );

// make the fields value to be accepted always, no matter what user actually inputed!
add_filter( 'acf/validate_value/name=clone_title', function ( $valid, 
    $value, $field, $input ) {
    return true;
}, 10, 4 );
```

With these 2 hooks you can achieve what you are looking for but on its simplest form. You could evolve much more both of these 2 hooks to perform much more sophisticated checks and rules depending on your needs.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, but this will affect every field called "title" that was cloned in a clone field right? Because I want to do that only for one particular field (namely the "title" field inside the "Section: services" group field, all fields of which are cloned in clone field "Services")

Answer (score 0):

##### I've understood your question by the following two lines:

> My "Section: Services" field group containing the "Title" field whose required status I wanna change in the clone field:

> My "Services" clone field containing "All fields from Section: Services field group" (it is within this clone field that I want my "Title" field to NOT be required any more):

##### According to what I understand, You want `"Title" required in "Section: Services"` & `"Title" NOT required in "Sections" (this group has clone of 'Section: Services')`

---

```
<?php
/**
 * Customize Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) field settings.
 *
 * @param array $field The field settings array.
 * @return array The modified field settings array.
 */
function acf_load_field_customization( $field ) {

    // $key_of_field_that_we_want_to_customize
    // We can use the key to customize both the clone or original field, so always work with the initial field_key.
    // Key of the "Title" field in the "Section : Services" field group.
    $title_field_key = "field_64c565905b3cd";


    // $key_of_field_that_is_cloned_of_other_field
    // Key of the "Services" field (cloned from the "Section : Services" field group).
    $services_field_key = "field_64c5660f4bc2b";

    // $key_of_field_or_group_we_clone_to_other_field
    // You use 'All fields' from XXX field group, so here use the key of that field group but If any particular field is being cloned, use its field_key here.
    // Key of the field group "Section : Services".
    $services_group_key = "group_64c5658c194e1";

    if (
        ! empty( $field['key'] )
        && isset( $field['clone'] ) && ! empty( $field['clone'] )
        && isset( $field['sub_fields'] ) && ! empty( $field['sub_fields'] )
        && $field['key'] == $services_field_key
        && in_array( $services_group_key, $field['clone'] )
    ) {
        // Loop through all cloned fields
        foreach ( $field['sub_fields'] as &$sub_field ) {
            if (
                isset( $sub_field['__key'] ) && ! empty( $sub_field['__key'] )
                && $sub_field['__key'] == $title_field_key // this means then current loop index is our cloned field of title 
            ) {
                $sub_field['required'] = 0; // Remove required from the clone of the "Title" field.
            }
        }
    }

    return $field;
}
add_filter( 'acf/load_field', 'acf_load_field_customization' );
```

---

##### Results

| before | after |
| --- | --- |
| [image: after_code] | [image: before_code] |

---

###### My answer does This -> "Title" required in "Section: Services" & "Title" NOT required in "Sections" (this group has clone of 'Section: Services')

###### **But** The alternatives take a different approach. -> "Title" NOT required in "Section: Services" & "Title" required in "Sections" (this group has clone of 'Section: Services')

###### This is the main confusion I had in my mind about what do you asked in question, so even if I miss understood maybe this other way may help somebody else

---

Your other follow-up question

> one issue though is that the ID of that field won't be the same on my local setup, on staging environment and on production environment. Is there a way to make it work on any environment?

For this export ACF groups from environment after task is done and import in production , field id will be same

---

##### This is data of both groups

I removed some unnecessary data for better readability

[image: field data]

---

| ACF settings & etc... |
| --- |
| [ACF field setup 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGX8r.png) |
| [ACF field setup 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dy1kI.png) |
| [ACF field setup 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fevYD.png) |
| [Section: Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6Fkc.png) |
| [Services - before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e97zH.png) |
| [Services - after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Un6hQ.png) |

Comment: Thanks @Yash. The issue is that I don't want to touch import or export because this project is a huge commercial website with tons of ACF groups used throughout the project. No chance I'm taking the risk to lose any data..